# Verify that Collection argument from all method calls will together contain all values from given collection

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a class to test that calls method from other class, that accepts a collection. I want to test, that all calls to this method together will contain all the values I expect, but the order and amount of calls is irrelevant.

I already implemented it without using mockito, but that anonymous class bothers me here:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    CubePos cubePos = new CubePos(0, 0, 0);

    Set<BlockPos> expected = new HashSet<>();
    BlockPos.getAllInBox(cubePos.getMinBlockPos(), cubePos.getMaxBlockPos()).forEach(expected::add);

    Set<BlockPos> actualPosSet = new HashSet<>();
    LightPropagator propagator = new LightPropagator() {
        @Override public void propagateLight(BlockPos centerPos, Iterable<BlockPos> coords, ILightBlockAccess blocks, EnumSkyBlock type,
                Consumer<BlockPos> setLightCallback) {
            coords.forEach(actualPosSet::add);
        }
    };

    FirstLightProcessor proc = makeProcessor(new TestLightBlockAccessImpl(20), propagator);
    proc.updateSkylightFor(cubePos);

    assertThat(actualPosSet, contains(expected));
}
```

(yes, the code is Minecraft-related, but the question isn't specific to that)

Comment: Why downvote? What is wrong with the question?

Comment: you probably dont need mockito here.. try to add the impl and a test case you tried

Comment: I actually don't have any of the code implemented yet (my existing implementation was very far from correct and I'm redesigning that part to be less broken and untestable by design). And I probably could do it without mockito, but that would mean creating implementation of that class, that would just have an internal collection, and add all values from the method argument, and then I would veryfy that it contains exactly the values I need.. Mockito just seemed loke a better approach to make the code easy to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `verify` and `ArgumentCaptor` from `mockito` to check the arguments passed to `propagator.propagateLight()`.

```
@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<Iterable<BlockPos>> captor;

@Test
public void test() {
  ...
  LightPropagator propagator = mock(LightPropagator.class);
  FirstLightProcessor proc = makeProcessor(new TestLightBlockAccessImpl(20), propagator);
  proc.updateSkylightFor(cubePos);

  verify(propagator).propagateLight(any(), captor.capture(), any(), any(), any())
  Iterable<BlockPos> actualValues = 
      captor.getAllValues()
           .stream()
           .flatMap(i -> StreamSupport.stream(i.spliterator(), false))
           .collect(toList()); 
  assertThat(actualValues, containsInAnyOrder(expected.toArray(new BlockPos[0])));
}
```

Comment: Based on ArgumentCaptor documentation, `getValue` will return only the last value, or is there something I'm missing and it does actually add all values from all calls into the iterator together? I need to verify that regardless of the amount of calls to that method, all of them together will contain all the values.

Comment: You can use `captor.getAllValues()` instead. I modified the answer.

Comment: actually, it seems like it needs to be a bit more complicated: 

`Iterable<BlockPos> actualValues = captor.getAllValues().stream().flatMap(i -> StreamSupport.stream(i.spliterator(), false)).collect(Collectors.toList());`
`assertThat(actualValues, containsInAnyOrder(expected.toArray(new BlockPos[0])));`

Comment: Sounds good. I could update the answer if that worked for you.